# Perform function on multiple columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data array of 30 trials(columns) each of 256 data points (rows) and would like to run a wavelet transform (which requires a 1D array) on each column with the eventual aim of obtaining the mean coefficients of the 30 trials.
Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: the right direction would be numpy but this is off-topic for SO

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multidimensional numpy array then you can use a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

# A is the matrix:  1 2 3
#                   4 5 6

for col in A.transpose():
    print("Column:", col)
    # Perform your wavelet transform here, you can save the
    # results to another multidimensional array.
```

This gives you access to each column as a 1D array.

Output:

```
Column:  [1 4]
Column:  [2 5]
Column:  [3 6]
```

If you want to access the rows rather than the columns then loop through `A` rather than `A.transpose()`.